# How Can I hide a content for specific page in css

Tags: css, text

How Can I hide a content for specific page in css.
I find on the internet some solutions but they only valid for element's id.
This code is an example

```
.page-id-47 #header-image-id { display: none; }
```

I want to apply this on a class not id because some content does not have id I tried to use this but it does not work with me:

```
.page-id-47 #header-image-class-name { display: none; }
```

and also this code is hide the class for the whole website:

```
.class-name{
       display:none;
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried `.page-id-47 .header-image-class-name {` (note the `.` instead of the `#`)?

Comment: Yes, I try this and it does not work

Comment: I usually achieve this by adding an extra class/ID to the page content wrapper itself (for example, to the section tag that contains the whole content of that page) and then in css, point to the element that I'm trying to hide USING the class/ID and apply `display: none` or `visibilty: hidden` as needed. Have you tried that?

Comment: No I didn't, How can I do this? I am using WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `visibility: hidden`, as shown below :-

```css
.myClass{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I am trying to solve. The class is disappeared but for whole website not for specified pages

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS

```
body .page-id-47 .header-image-class-name { 
display: none;
}
```

After body give a space and type .page-id-47 .header-image-class-name {display: none;}

Comment: Thanks for help, I try it and does not work for me.